# What is the use of "static" keyword with Variables, functions and objects of classes etc?

Tags: c++, static, keyword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [static function/variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195412/static-function-variable)

Tell me the different combination of static like object static and variable normal , or variable static function normal , object static function normal etc etc

Comment: If you touch them, you'll get zapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static variable and function are limited in scope they are declared in. Additionally, variables defined in functions will persist their value across function calls if defined as static.

A static method or member on an object can be used directly without a specific instance of the object, i.e. no this pointer will be automatically passed into the method. Naturally this means you can only access other static methods and variables from within a static method.